# Merge values of consecutive rows if they have the same values on a different column (AWK)

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I need to combine the first value (`$1`) of consecutive rows if their fourth value (`$4`) is the same (`I-PER`).

I managed to filter the values I need simply using awk:

```
awk ' ($4 == "I-PER") {printf $1; printf "\n" }
```

I also found how to merge rows with duplicate column values but not consecutive ones.

Example (Input):

```
Comandante  comandante  NP00000 I-PER
de  de  SPS00   I-PER
la  el  DA0FS0  I-PER
Guardia guardia NP00000 I-PER
Civil   civil   NP00000 I-PER
Pamplona    pamplona    NP00000 I-LOC
Poblador    poblador    NP00000 I-PER
```

Example (Output):

```
Comandante de la Guardia Civil
Poblador
```

Comment: Did you forget the final apostrophe `'` in the `awk` command here? I hesitate to just correct it because of [Please don't correct commands in questions unless you are sure the mistake is not the source of the problem](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17649/507051)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `awk` solution to avoid printing repeated `\n`ewlines if condition didn't meet in any line:

```
awk '($4=="I-PER"){ printf SEP$1; SEP=" "; C=1; next } 
      C==1{ SEP=""; print ""; C=0} END{print ""}' infile
```

example input:

```
Comandante  comandante  NP00000 I-PER
de  de  SPS00   I-PER
la  el  DA0FS0  I-PER
Guardia guardia NP00000 I-PER
Civil   civil   NP00000 I-PER
no I-PER in fourth column
anotherline no I-PER in fourth column
Pamplona    pamplona    NP00000 I-LOC
Poblador    poblador    NP00000 I-PER
```

The output is:

```
Comandante de la Guardia Civil
Poblador
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and somewhat dirty solution with a ternary operator (`condition?true:false`), it does the test you provided and prints either `$1` followed by space or a newline:

```bsh
awk '{printf $4=="I-PER"?$1" ":"\n"}'
```

Output:

```bsh
$ <test awk '{printf $4=="I-PER"?$1" ":"\n"}'
Comandante de la Guardia Civil 
Poblador
```

---

Here's a quite poor alternative approach with an array – at least this doesn't produce empty lines like the above does for multiple successive non-`I-PER` lines:

```bsh
awk '{
  if ($4=="I-PER") {a[i++]=$1}
  else if (length(a)>0) {
    for (i in a) {printf a[i]" ";delete a[i]}
    print ""
    }
  }
 END {
  if (length(a)>0) {
    for (i in a) printf a[i]" ";print ""}
  }'
```

Output:

```bsh
$ <test awk '{if($4=="I-PER"){a[i++]=$1}else if(length(a)>0){for(i in a){printf a[i]" ";delete a[i]};print ""}}END{if(length(a)>0){for(i in a)printf a[i]" ";print ""}}'
Comandante de la Guardia Civil 
Poblador
```